# R package grid disappeared?

Tags: r

R package `grid` seems to be part of some recent answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29346910/684229 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/62772/4630). However, R refuses to install the package and at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grid/index.html I learn that grid package was removed from CRAN repository! With no other information where all its features can be found... I doubt it simply got lost without a replacement?

Comment: I think `grid` is a base package. Don't you have it already installed? Did you try `library(grid)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg OMG I had a heart attack today when I saw that `grid` was archived.  I was WTF, how is that possible!!!  Phew.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

David Arenburg is correct.  According to the [`grid` changelog](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/doc/changes.txt), it became a base package with version 1.8.0.  Therefore, it no longer needs to be available on the CRAN repository.

Since it is a base package, it should come pre-installed with all newer versions of R.